# How to analyze fractional crossover design (factional survey experiment) with 3 factors in R?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, crossover-study

I have the following experimental design: my treatment is composed out of three factors (`factor1`, `factor2`, `factor3` ) each having two levels. So far I have eight groups and I assigned subjects randomly to these groups.

To raise the power of the study, I thought it was a good idea to test each subject twice. After testing the first treatment, there is a second treatment to the same person, this second treatment is composed out of all the opposite factor levels.

I don't know how exactly this design is called, looks like a fractional crossover design (or some kind of factional survey experiment) to me.

The response variable is continuous, so I am going for an ANOVA (or should I give the `nlme package` a try?). Now I am struggling with the right way to do it regarding the following four points.

1. Does this model formula fit to the design?

   ```
   fit = aov(response ~ factor1 * factor2 * factor3 + Error(subject / (factor1 * factor2 * factor3))
   ```
2. And what is the difference to the following formula?

   ```
   fit = aov(response ~ (factor1 * factor2 * factor3) + Error(subject))
   ```
3. What if I am only interested in the following effects?

   - Main effect of `factor1`
   - Main effect of `factor2`
   - Interaction of `factor1` x `factor3`
   - Interaction of `factor2` x `factor3`
4. And how do I interpret the output given the above formulas?